# Create cuts automatically by audio wave form in Premiere Pro CC

Tags: premiere, audio, automation

I always cut my videos of the trips I'm doing. And I noticed that it is often the same that I cut out the parts where nothing is said and keep only the parts where somebody is talking.
Is there a plugin or a way in Premiere Pro CC to automatically create the cuts in a sequence where the audio changes from a lower to a higher value than a certain threshold?

Answer (score -1):

Not that I've heard of, however, you could add Dynamics / Compression to your audio track and essentially compress out the low gain sections.

On your Audio Mixer Window, drop down the the filter section at top for the track all your audio resides on.

You will want to add Compression, not Expansion. Add some Gain MarkUp, 5-10 dB. Check Limiter, set to -2 dB.  Then adjust the ratio/gate/threshold so that the compressor will do as follows:

Add 5-10 dB of Gain to the entire track; depending on your source, you'll need to adjust that by levels/ear.

The gate/ratio will then if set correctly, only allow anything "Above" "X dB" to pass through the threshhold.

Loud sounds will be MarkUped as well, however, the compressor will not overmodulate if you adjust correctly and use the Limiter.

So if your video is nothing but low "breeze" noise, it will be cut to zero. Audio will need to "pass" the threshhold, and the attack setting will adjust how fast it allows passable audio to become audible and how fast it closes the gate after the audio falls below threshhold.

It sounds more complicated than it really is. If you follow the steps, play with the settings, you'll get it.

The filter is called **DYNAMICS**